# Application crash on some devices with android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setDecorPadding

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-framelayout, androiddesignsupport

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage/com.mypackage.activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setDecorPadding(int, int, int, int)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6286)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setDecorPadding(int, int, int, int)' on a null object reference
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.applyFixedSizeWindow(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:537)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:331)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
       at com.watchlivetv.onlineradioapp.activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:99)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6778)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1121)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2675)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6286)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I have seen above a crash on a console for some user.please see more details from here http://crashes.to/s/c98e1c603ef

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mainToolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        actionBar = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.zalunuActionBar);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar.setTabListener(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MainPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(viewPager.getChildCount());
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

    }
```

Here,I have update mainActivity code there is viewpager with 4 fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include layout="@layout/drawer" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is R.layout.activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mainToolBar"
            style="@style/toolbar"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

            <include layout="@layout/activity_main_custom_action_bar" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bannerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also used Appodeal and Admob ads in my application.so initialization of that SDK is also done in this activity.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "projectId"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 41
        versionName "5.0.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : OneSignalID,
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    implementation files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
    implementation project(':appiraterandroidmaster')
    implementation project(path: ':vitamio')
    implementation files('libs/appodeal-2.1.7.jar')
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jdom2-2.0.6.jar')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    /*admod mediation*/
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:7.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:applovin:7.6.0.0'
    implementation('com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:5.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:vungle:5.3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:7.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:6.2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:3.2.1.1'
    //    admob mediation end
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/OneAudience-sdk-release-6.0.0.0.jar')
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: probably a mismatch between sdk and app compat library. What is the version of your app compat library?

Comment: @Henry appcompat have version `26.1.0`

Comment: put your java code here, where error is occurred.

Comment: @GunduBandagar there is only one ViewPager you can check it details from here http://crashes.to/s/c98e1c603ef

Comment: i saw that but i want to see your HomeActivity onCreate code, where getting error.

Comment: @GunduBandagar updated the MainActivity Oncreate

Comment: hmm.. post your R.layout.activity_main file

Comment: @HenryI have updated the xml file.

Comment: Can you make sure, that your activity has an `AppCompat` theme applied to it?

Comment: @azizbekian , activity has Appcompat theme

Comment: Is this question still open? If so, please post your build.gradle.

Comment: @Yuliwee yes it's still open, I have added  build.gradle

Comment: Change `com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2` to version 26.1.0 to be the same as in the other support dependencies.

Comment: i have already tried that solution but not working

Comment: Please also check that you only have ond type of support library, e.g. only v7.

Answer (score 4):

The error is because of conflict between support libraries.
You used support.v4 library and support.v7 library both. Please use only one support library then the problem will be fixed.

Comment: i have used `gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath` for degub there is no conflict i have only `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:` in code. and `com.android.support:support-v4:` also update gradle.build file

Comment: I am facing the same issue and no dependency conflict. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have debug your error. It will be throw only in one condition as per my debug.

when you are getting null at AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:489

```
final ViewGroup windowContentView = (ViewGroup) mWindow.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

so this line never be called AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:502

```
contentView.setId(android.R.id.content);
```

which internally lead to your error. you will get cfl null at AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:530

```
ContentFrameLayout cfl = (ContentFrameLayout) mSubDecor.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

and error will thrown at AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:537

```
cfl.setDecorPadding(windowDecor.getPaddingLeft(),
            windowDecor.getPaddingTop(), windowDecor.getPaddingRight(),
            windowDecor.getPaddingBottom());
```

mWindow is set internally by android at activity init which is object of PhoneWindow

but if any one try to use your application on any other place then mobile means (in virtual machine or running some script to hack it) then it may occur that issue.

So you should check on which device that is occurring and it is also run on google certified os or not.

Comment: http://crashes.to/s/c98e1c603ef here all details are the mention of the device  that causes the issue, how can I resolve this bug?as per log major bugs are on `chrombook`

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers I am not able to see more detail in crash report due to I am not part of your team in fabric and I don't have right to view that

Comment: 90% of the crash is reported on `Asus Chromebook Flip C100PA` android version 7

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `ContentFrameLayout` is meant for internal use. [Looking at its source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/415f740/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/ContentFrameLayout.java) it doesn't really seem to do anything and the entire class is marked as `@hide` which is probably why you get the error (assume you already add the dependency in your apps build gradle). While I'm sure the class has some I internal purpose for the appcompat library. For the app developers, we should probably stick to using regular `FrameLayout`.

Comment: what is a solution for this?can we do anything for the solution?

Comment: just replace ContentFrameLayout with FrameLayout. ContentFrameLayout is just and wrapper class for FrameLayout

Comment: I have not used `ContentFrameLayout`, may it's in a library that I have used. how to identify where it's used?how to replace it if it's from some library.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same bug. I think maybe the `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` caused this bug.  I have changed it to `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. It seems improved. You can try it.