# Application crashes sometimes on androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setDecorPadding() method

Tags: android, androidx

Sometimes, I get this crash while my app is opening:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setDecorPadding(int, int, int, int)' on a null object reference
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.applyFixedSizeWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1026)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:820)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onPostCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:527)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:127)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1381)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3499)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

As you can see, there's no reference to something in my code in the stack trace so for this reason I'm not able to figure out what the problem is. What could be the cause of this crash?.

Comment: I think this posts answers this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842279/application-crash-on-some-devices-with-android-support-v7-widget-contentframelay/48030050#48030050

Comment: @DivakarLuffy I'm using AndroidX dependencies in my project and not Support Libraries

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I was getting this error in production when I load the first screen. I also use androidx and no Support Libraries. Some times this crash looks like:

```java
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
Window couldn't find content container view ***.onCreate
```

Unfortunately, I still don't understand what exactly the error is but I found this [post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37095334?pli=1#comment2). I changed `onCreate` method to:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     getWindow().getDecorView();
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
}
```

Just added `getWindow().getDecorView();` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and it solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

Add as null check before calling this method

```
if (YourContentFrameLayout != null)
   YourContentFrameLayout.setDecorPadding(intvalue,intvalue,intvalue,intvalue);
```

Comment: I'm not using any ContentFrameLayout directly. It seems there's a library widget that uses this component internally, I'm wondering if it is ConstraintLayout

Comment: You must getting line number in the log itself, check that once.

Comment: I don't see any references to my code. Looking at the code of the internal API classes, I noticed that the exception is being thrown here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegateImpl.java#1026